# Selenium Web driver select data from drop down by reading drop down value from excel sheet

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, jxl

I am trying to select drop down value by reading drop down value from excel. I tried following code however, it is not selecting value as per data mentioned in the excel sheet. For me all data are populating correctly in the respective field except Gender drop down.

following are Screen shot of HTML code and UI:

[image: UI Image]

[image: Xpath Information]

[image: HTML Code]

Following are my HTML code:

```
<td class="codetable last-cell" headers="N224AA-4-2">
<div id="widget___o3id7" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitLeft codetable dijitTextBox dijitComboBox" lang="en-US" role="listbox" dir="ltr" widgetid="__o3id7" aria-expanded="false">
<div class="dijitReset dijitRight dijitButtonNode dijitArrowButton dijitDownArrowButton dijitArrowButtonContainer" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-point="_buttonNode, _popupStateNode" popupactive="true">
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitArrowButtonInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="▼ ">
</div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="Χ ">
</div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
<input id="__o3id7" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="textbox" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" tabindex="0" title="Gender Mandatory" size="1" value="Male" aria-owns="__o3id7_popup" aria-activedescendant="__o3id7_popup1">
<input type="hidden" name="__o3id7" value="SX1">
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

I populated test data in the excel sheet as below where "Female" is drop down value:

```
UserName password123    100000005   Elena   Sawyerehde  Female
```

Following are my code:

```
package com.access;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class Registration {

    static WebDriver driver;

      @BeforeMethod
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Directory\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }

      @Test 
      public void TestCase1() throws Exception {
          FileInputStream fi=new FileInputStream("C:\\File\\Book2.xls");
          Workbook w=Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
          Sheet s=w.getSheet(0);
       driver.get("https://example.com");

        try
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.getRows(); i++)
        {
        //Read data from excel sheet
            String s1 = s.getCell(0,i).getContents();
            String s2 = s.getCell(1,i).getContents();
            String s3 = s.getCell(2,i).getContents();
            String s4 = s.getCell(3,i).getContents();
            String s5 = s.getCell(4,i).getContents();
            String s6 = s.getCell(5,i).getContents();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/form/input[1]")).sendKeys(s1);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/form/input[2]")).sendKeys(s2);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/a/span/span/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Assert.assertEquals("Testing Hub", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='app-banner']/div[1]/div/h2")).getText());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span[1]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);         
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/span/span/span/span[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);         
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);     
            driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-curam_ModalDialog_0");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='__o3id0']")).sendKeys(s3);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/form/div/div[5]/a[1]/span/span/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Assert.assertEquals("There are no matching items based on the Search Criteria entered.", driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div/ul/li/div")).getText());
            Thread.sleep(1000);         
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[2]/a/span/span/span")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);         
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/form/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys(s4);
            Thread.sleep(1000);         
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/form/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/input")).sendKeys(s5);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("___o3id7"))).selectByValue(s6);
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            }    
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            System.out.println(e);

            }
            }
}
```

Comment: the input type is text. Are you sure it is a select element? Also it has readonly property to true, so not sure if you can update anything...

Comment: I can use send key for Input type but I want to also use drop down value by reading from Excel Sheet. So It has both capability input value in the field as well as select value from the drop down.

Comment: Hi Curious, When does the value 'Female' shows up. I guess upon clicking the dropdown it will show the value 'Female'. Am I right??

Comment: Yes, when I click on drop down then Female option show up. And Male option display by default selected option.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no Select tag in the code you pasted, using `select` for clicking dropdown won't help.

As per your test script and Html code the `id` value for the dropdown is different.

`//*[@id='widget___o3id7']` - used in the xpath to select dropdown, where in the html code `id = "__o3id7"`.

Try after changing them

Its better to share your UI to understand the scenario and come to a conclusion

---

Thanks for sharing the UI and HTML code.

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("__o3id7")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1500);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Female')]")).click();
```

Replace your `select` statement and try this codes. Lets hope this would click 'Female' from your drop down.

Comment: Hi Anand - I updated id as you suggested and I also provided UI screen shot and HTML and Xpath infoation in the screen shot.

Comment: @Curious did my answer helped you

Comment: No, Anand you answer did not help.